# NSMutableArray Description Method - Array of Arrays

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have an Array that contains array objects. An array of Arrays. When I apply the description method to the Array, I don't see the data in the inner arrays. Here is the code:

```
[runScoreDataArray addObject:[NSString stringWithString:currentUser]];
[runScoreDataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:mainScores.scoreTotal]];

NSLog(@"Array1 contains: %@", [runScoreDataArray description]);

// Now add the array runScoreDataArray to the Array highScoresArray
[highScoresArray addObject: runScoreDataArray];

// Empty the runScoresData Array after each run.
[runScoreDataArray removeAllObjects];

NSLog(@"Array2 contains: %@", [highScoresArray description]);
```

The NSLog printout for runScoresDataArray reads as it should:
Array1 contains: (USER1,34500)

The NSLog for highScoresArray reads:
ARRAY2 contains: ((),(),())

I was expecting to see the data for each array element in the NSLog printout, rather than the empty brackets.

Question: How can I use the description method to printout the contents of an array of arrays?

Comment: Quick question: Are Objective-C arrays reference types, or value types?

Comment: The arrays being used here are NSMutableArrays, instances of which are references. (Obj-C supports C-style arrays also, but it's clear that's not happening here because messages are being sent to them.)

Comment: I was hoping to get the OP replying. Because the act of answering that simple question makes the bug in the code obvious.

Comment: Ah. I didn't hear the Socratic intonation. ;)

Comment: OP here - yes, looks like I was clobbering the data in the original arrays and left only with references to empty space. Many thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `-addObject:` the `runScoreDataArray` to `highScoresArray`, it's not copying the values in the array, it's adding a reference to the actual `runScoreDataArray` to the parent array.

So when you then go and clear out the `runScoreDataArray` with `-removeAllObjects`, that affects the reference inside the highScoresArray as well.

Depending on what you're after, you might want something like:

```
[highScoresArray addObject: [NSArray arrayWithArray:runScoreDataArray]];
```

to insert a shallow copy.